# UV map is showing only half object

Tags: uv, mirror

When I UV unwrap my object I get only one side (it was built using the mirror mod, but I did apply it before unwrapping).
If I smart unwrap it both side appears. I can not understand why.
Any ideas? Thank you[image]

Comment: Hello  If that seam is indeed perfect (one connected loop) then make sure the 2 UV islands are not overlapping (UV >> Pack islands). Try adding another seam, check if that will affect the UV map or if it remains the same after that, select the entire mesh and Unwrap again. Select parts of the mesh and check the UV map to see if any of the selected parts appear there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I was trying all of that except the ´pack islands´, so maybe you were right! I eventually circumnavigating the problem creating asymmetrical seams (like you said), and eventually now the UV maps resembles more what I expect it to be. But I'm still unsure of the original problem, so next time I will remember your words (how can I give you an UP reputation? I'm still new here)